# How to set PARTITION_ID in AZURE EVENT HUB using Python

Tags: python, azure

Im a newbie to Azure Event Hub.

I have initialized 3 partitions in Event Hub. I am using the following code to set Partition_id in Python. I am using EventHub 'Capture' to store the events in Azure Blob Storage.

The Code below executes but stores event files in Azure Blob Storage, in ALL (3) partiton folders rather than just the 2nd partition folder.

Additionally, I printed 'print(event_data_batch)' on console whose value ia shown 2, which shows that partition_id is getting value '2' assigned.

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub import EventData
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient

EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR = "..."
EVENT_HUB_NAME = "....."

async def run():
\# Create a producer client to send messages to the event hub.
\# Specify a connection string to your event hubs namespace and
\# the event hub name.
producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(
conn_str=EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR, eventhub_name=EVENT_HUB_NAME
)
async with producer:
\# Create a batch.
event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch(**partition_id="2"**)
\# Add events to the batch.
event_data_batch.add(EventData("First event---"))
event_data_batch.add(EventData("Second event---"))
event_data_batch.add(EventData("Third event---"))
event_data_batch.add(EventData("Fourth event---"))
event_data_batch.add(EventData("Fifth event---"))
event_data_batch.add(EventData("Sixth event---"))

        # Send the batch of events to the event hub.
        await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
        print(event_data_batch)
        print('Batch Sent')

asyncio.run(run())
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Raheel If we set the partition count is 2 in event hub, we can use to get only one partition_ID=1.

Comment: @DasariKamali I have edited the question, hope it clarifies the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The partition_ID is always less than the partition count in the Azure event hub. I have 3 partition counts in my event hub as below,

[image]

With partition_ID=3, I got the KeyError as below error,

[image]

**Code :**

```py
async def run():
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(
conn_str=EVENT_HUB_CONNECTION_STR, eventhub_name=EVENT_HUB_NAME
)
    async with producer:
        event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch(partition_id="2")
        event_data_batch.add(EventData("First event---"))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData("Second event---"))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData("Third event---"))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData("Fourth event---"))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData("Fifth event---"))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData("Sixth event---"))

        await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)
        print(event_data_batch)
        print('Batch Sent')

asyncio.run(run())
```

**Output :**

Then, I gave partition_ID=2 it runs successfully as below,

[image]